# How to reset PyCharm editor?

Tags: pycharm

I have a vertical line on my editor but am not sure how to remove it. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling PyCharm to resolve this issue.

I am currently using PyCharm Community Edition 2017.2.4.

[image: PyCharm Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That "vertical line" indicates that you should not write more than some characters in a line. This is a common practice for programming.

If you don't want pycharm to show it, deselect this:

```
Settings/Preferences -> Editor -> General -> Appearance -> Show right margin
```

Comment: I wasn't sure how I enabled it in the first place but I was able to turn off, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @halfelf's answer: if you want to make use of the right margin you can also configure its position to fit your coding style, in `Editor -> Code Style` (at least in my older PyCharm version):
[image]